# Jasmine.js V2.0.0 - read fixtures data - TypeError: undefined is not a function at Object

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I am new to jasmine.js framework.

What is the problem in this code:

```
beforeEach(function(){
     var fixtureUrl     = "/../path/to/templates/home.html";
     var html = jasmine.getFixtures().read(fixtureUrl);
     console.log(html);
});
```

I am getting a error:

**TypeError: undefined is not a function at Object.**

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function at Object<anonymous> (http://{MY_LOCAL_DOMAIN}/test/jasmine2/spec/home.view.spec.js:15:23)
    at attemptSync (http://{MY_LOCAL_DOMAIN}/test/jasmine2/libs/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine.js:1510:12)
    at QueueRunner.run (http://{MY_LOCAL_DOMAIN}/test/jasmine2/libs/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine.js:1498:9)
    at QueueRunner.execute (http://{MY_LOCAL_DOMAIN}/test/jasmine2/libs/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine.js:1485:10)
    at Spec.Env.queueRunnerFactory (http://{MY_LOCAL_DOMAIN}/test/jasmine2/libs/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine.js:518:35)
    at Spec.execute (http://{MY_LOCAL_DOMAIN}/test/jasmine2/libs/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine.js:306:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://{MY_LOCAL_DOMAIN}/test/jasmine2/libs/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine.js:1708:37)
    at attemptAsync (http://{MY_LOCAL_DOMAIN}/test/jasmine2/libs/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine.js:1520:12)
    at QueueRunner.run (http://{MY_LOCAL_DOMAIN}/test/jasmine2/libs/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine.js:1496:16)
    at QueueRunner.execute (http://{MY_LOCAL_DOMAIN}/test/jasmine2/libs/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine.js:1485:10)
```

I am using:
**Jasmine.js, Jasmine-html.js and boot.js from jasmine version 2.0.0** and   **Jasmine-jQuery Version 2.1.0**

In my application, I am using spec.config.js to load all necessary file includes: in this order:

```
 paths: {
     ...,
     ...,
     ...,
    'jasmine': '../test/jasmine2/libs/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine',    
    'jasmine-html':'../test/jasmine2/libs/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine-html',    
    'boot': '../test/jasmine2/libs/jasmine-2.0.0/boot',    
    'jasmine-jquery':'../test/jasmine2/libs/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine-jquery',    
    'sinon': '../test/jasmine2/libs/sinon-1.9.1/sinon',
}
```

And I have defined into my spec file as:

```
 describe('Home', function() {   

     define(['views/home.view','jasmine','jasmine-jquery'], function(HomeView,Jasmine,JasmineJQuery) {
    ....
         var home_view      = new HomeView();
         var jasmine        = Jasmine;
         var jasmine_jquery = JasmineJQuery;
    ....
    });
    beforeEach(function(){
         var fixtureUrl     = "/../path/to/templates/home.html";
         var html = jasmine.getFixtures().read(fixtureUrl);
         console.log(html);
    });
    it('should check home is rendred', function() {
          {SOME TESTING HERE...}
    });

});
```

Can any one help me to read fixtures data and check toHaveId("{SOME_DIV_ID}")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to order the .js files in this order:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jasmine2/libs/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jasmine2/libs/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jasmine2/libs/jasmine-2.0.0/boot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/libs/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jasmine2/libs/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine-jquery.js"></script>
```

In your spec file, you can globally defined your view object as:

```
 describe('View', function() {
     'use strict';
     {VARIABLE_DECLARATIONS}
     var fixtureUrl = "/path/to/fixture/fixture.html";

    define(['views/home.view','jasmine','jasmine-jquery'], 
       function(HomeView,Jasmine,JasmineJQuery) {
           {CREATE OBJECTS IF NECESSARY...}

           describe('Initialize', function() {  
                 beforeEach(function(){
                      var html = jasmine.getFixtures().read(fixtureUrl);
                      jasmine.getFixtures().set(html);              
                });
               it('should check initializeView is called ', function() {
                    {YOUR_CODE_HERE...for test from the fixtures};
                    //expect($('{CONTAINER_ELEMENT_ID}').get(0)).toHaveId("{DIV_ID}");
               });  
           });                        
     });
});
```

I hope this helps.